# Rename "about" page link

Tags: feature-request

After reading the blog entry "[About Page 2.0: The QuickStartening](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/about-page-2-0-the-quickstartening/)" I was a bit confused.
It links to [Figuring Out What They Expected](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000058.html) which says

> They [new users] have some expectations of how they think the program is going to work. If they've used similar software before, they will think it's going to work like that other software. If they've used any software before, they are going to think that your software conforms to certain common conventions

In my opinion it is a very common convention to fill the about page with some kind of a portfolio of the company/site and not with a introduction for new users.
**This might prevent new users from going there even if they were interested in a "HowTo use this site**".

I would propose to at least rename the link to this page into something more fitting like

- Getting started
- [SiteName] 101
- How To?
- (many good names that I will not mention here)
- [your idea]

Comment: "Getting Started" and "Site Name 101" are both just plain too long. There's a limited amount of space up there in the top bar and those would eat too much of it up. If the alternative isn't a single word, it's probably not going to happen.

Comment: @animuson: I know these are not good. I just did not want to post without any proposal. Also I would not replace the "about" in the top line because it is too small to attract new user's attention.

Comment: Personally I'm a big fan of **"New User? Click Here"** links. I always look for them first when I'm interested in using a new site.

Comment: The "101" thing might also not translate very well internationally.

Comment: Where do they click if they want to find about what the site is?

Comment: @random: As I already said I would not replace the about link on top of the page.

Comment: You're going to have to show where people are more inclined to click a link that doesn't say "About" if they want to read about what a site is about.

Comment: @random: Ok let me put it another way: The content of the about page is actually a mix of an about page and an introduction to using the site. When linking to this page via "about" you lose those who search the introduction and via "introduction" you lose the "about"ies. Either you link the same page twice and get all of them or you split the page and link seperately.

Answer (score 2):

**Yup, "About" isn't the right name.  We just haven't figured out the right one yet.**

**"Quick Start Guide"** is a good analogue to consumer electronics, in that it's the easy, minimum you need to read to get going (and *not* the longer, more reference-like manual).  But it's not the kind of term you expect on a website, where a "guide" sounds long.

**"Get Started"** or **"Start Here"** seem less out of place, but they may be mistaken for a login page link.

You're right though, and it's pretty safe to say that it won't stay as "About" for too long.

Comment: It also welcomes people with their first shiny bronze badge if they get to the bottom of it, why not call it `/welcome`? This also gives people a nice word to use in comment links to new users, e.g. "[Welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/welcome) to Stack Overflow! We'd like to help, but we need more information. What are you using to frob the fizzywinkle that inherits the gobstopper class?"